# cant echo on remote server using capistrano

Tags: ubuntu, capistrano

using the command line it works:

```
$ ssh user@remote.vm.net
password:
> echo ping
ping
```

with capistrano:

```
# set :use_sudo, true
set :pty, true
set :user, 'user'
set :password, 'password'

set :stage, :production
role :web, 'remote.vm.net'

task :ping do
  on roles(:web) do
    execute 'echo ping'
  end
end
```

it doesn't:

```
$ cap production ping
INFO [7db945a1] Running /usr/bin/env echo ping on remote.vm.net
DEBUG [7db945a1] Command: echo ping
cap aborted!
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I want to say the execute command doesn't run a shell.  echo is a command provided by the shell.  Try using the "run" command instead of "execute".

Also note that both run and execute are deprecated in the newest versions.

Comment: true, what do i use instead of run / execute?